# Anyone having issues with Safari and external links back to your rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, safari, stripe-payments

I have a rails app with sorcery for authentication. I'm trying to get Stripe checkout integrated but I'm seeing an issue with Safari. Works fine with Chrome and Firefox.

I can successfully create a Stripe hosted checkout page with the cancel url and the stripe js sends me there in the same browser tab. Problem is when I click on the cancel/back link on the checkout page it goes back to my app and punts me to the login page as it can't find the session and current_user is nil.

Funny thing is that on the login page if I simply type in the cancel url into the address bar it authenticates me successfully so it must find the original session/cookie.

Has anyone encountered this? Is it a caching issue? I see no errors in the log nor in the js console. Just this in the server log...

`Filter chain halted as :require_login rendered or redirected`

And it's nothing to do with Stripe either as I created a simple test.html page on another server and different domain with a link to the cancel url. Same result. I see the same issue going from https back to my localhost server as well as in a staging environment https -> https.

I've also cleared my Safari cache, history, cookies, restarted the browser and my computer and cleared the rails sessions table to no avail. I'm using activerecord session store but also tried with plain cookies.

Any hints/solutions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Update: if I open the cancel url in a new browser tab it works. Just the same tab doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is apparently a known bug with Safari as of Feb 19 2021. Safari won't send the cookie if it's set to Lax. Rails 6 defaults are lax now where < 6 is wasn't set.